# How can I put (parts of) a large object graph in Rails.cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a class in which looking up an instance is expensive, so instances are cached:

```
class Foo
  def self.find(id)
    Rails.cache.fetch("Foo.#{id}") do
      // some expensive lookup, like an HTTParty request, or a long SQL query
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

That works fine until `Foo`s have related `Foo`s:

```
class Foo
  def children
    @child_foo_ids.map { |id| Foo.find(id) }
  end
end
```

I'd like to use `||=` caching to save repeated trips:

```
class Foo
  def children
    @children ||= @child_foo_ids.map { |id| Foo.find(id) }
  end
end
```

But `Rails.cache` freezes the found `Foo`s, so I can't set the instance variable after I create and cache the object.  (i.e. this method raises a `TypeError`.)

One solution would be to pre-fetch the `parent` when I first do the expensive find, but that could end up loading a **gigantic** object graph when I only want one or two instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* use `||=` caching; you just have to use a little indirection:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @related_objects = {}
  end
  def children
    @related_objects[:children] ||= @child_foo_ids.map { |id| Foo.find(id) }
  end
end
```

`Rails.cache` won't freeze the instance variables of each `Foo`, so that `Hash` can be modified!

PS: yes, I did just post this question and the answer at essentially the same time.  I figured the community could benefit from my struggle.